# Setup Wi-Fi from an Android app

Tags: android, android-wifi, kiosk-mode, android-settings

Android app which i am developing has some modes like:

- Kiosk Mode
- Normal Mode
- Semi-Kiosk Mode

Now my question is while my app is running in a Kiosk mode it will blocks all the other apps to open/make himself on the top. So user is unable to go to the settings screen.

I want a way to provide a Wi-Fi settings within my app so that user can do:

1. Search for the Wi-Fi nearby
2. Select and provide the password
3. Can see which Wi-Fi node is connected

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: android.net.wifi seems to provide all the functionality you need, particularly the WifiManager. What's the issue exactly?

Comment: Yes, got your point. Can yo provide a link or sample code for the same, it will save my time.

Comment: Is there someone, who's not understand the question context. Please behave in a professional way and if any doubt or query, should asked as a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old, but just in case it saves someone a little bit of research in the future this is a solution that I came up with for a similar use case.

Just use the activity that Android provides for managing wifi (without the user seeing the rest of the settings) by manually assembling an intent like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.net.wifi.SETUP_WIFI_NETWORK");
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.settings/com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSetupActivity"));
intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
startActivity(intent);
```